# What is the Scala way to process a file line by line in parallel, with back pressure?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, backpressure

The following code will read a file line by line, create a task for each line and then queue it up to the executor. If the executor's queue is full, the reading from the file stops until there is space again.

I looked at a few suggestions in SO, but they all either require the entire content of the file be read into memory, or suboptimal scheduling (e.g. read 100 lines, process them in parallel, only after that finishes, read the next 100 lines). I also don't want to use libraries like Akka for this.

What is the Scala way of achieving this, without those drawbacks?

```
  val exec = executorWithBoundedQueue()
  val lines = Source.fromFile(sourceFile, cs).getLines()
  lines.map {
    l => exec.submit(new Callable[String] {
      override def call(): String = doStuff(l)
    })
  }.foreach {
    s => consume(s.get())
  }
  exec.shutdown()
```

Illustrative definition of `executorWithBoundedQueue`

```
def executorWithBoundedQueue(): ExecutorService = {
    val boundedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue[Runnable](1000)
    new ThreadPoolExecutor(boundedQueue)
}
```

Comment: I know you said no Akka but Akka Streams would fit nicely here.

Comment: Apache Spark would work

Comment: Can you show more about the definition of `executorWithBoundedQueue()`?

Comment: @mattinbits: added it to the question

Comment: It feels like a lot of fuss to use Akka just so that I can use some threads. Spark is also way overkill IMO...

Comment: So, your `executorWithBoundedQueue` will take care of blocking. Can you say more about why the version you have above doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: @mattimbits: It does meet my requirements, but it's very Java. I would have thought Scala has its own way to do it as concurrency seems to be its big focus